# Fill NaN with 0 or 0 list/numpy array with the same dimension as other nonzero values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Different columns have different data types, e.g., `int, float, numpy.array, list`. For example, the input is:

```
lst1 = [nan, nan, 1, 2]
lst2 = [1.25, 2.3, nan, 3.2]
lst3 = [[1,2], nan, nan, [4,0]]
lst4 = [nan, np.array([[1,2,3],[6,7,5]]), np.array([[4,0,2],[9,2,3]]), nan]
lsts = [lst1, lst2, lst3, lst4]
columns = ['lst1','lst2','lst3','lst4']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
for lst, column in zip(lsts, columns):
    df[column] = lst
```

df:

```
    lst1    lst2    lst3    lst4
0   NaN     1.25    [1, 2]  NaN
1   NaN     2.30    NaN     [[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 5]]
2   1.0     NaN     NaN     [[4, 0, 2], [9, 2, 3]]
3   2.0     3.20    [4, 0]  NaN
```

The expected output is:

```
    lst1    lst2    lst3    lst4
0   0       1.25    [1, 2]  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
1   0       2.30    [0, 0]  [[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 5]]
2   1       0.00    [0, 0]  [[4, 0, 2], [9, 2, 3]]
3   2       3.20    [4, 0]  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

I tried `df.fillna(0, inplace = True)` but it was not filling 0 list/numpy array. How to have this adaptive filling? Thank you!

Comment: This is (partially) why we would/should avoid storing array/lists/objects in dataframes, not to mention the complication of object references.

Comment: What is `nan`? `np.nan`? Did you try `pd.NA`?

Comment: The `df` here is an example. The `nan` is the result of reading empty value into `df` from an excel. And I checked the types of some `nan` it showed `<class 'numpy.float64'>` or
`<class 'float'>`.